# Ifelse statement with multiple conditions using dplyr::mutate/mutate_if

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I would like to create a new variable such that it is `1` if any of the variables from a set of variables is `1` or `0` otherwise, using the `dplyr::mutate` and base `any` functions.

**Dataset:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, METFORMIN = c(0L, 0L), SULPHONYLUREA = c(0L, 0L), MEGLITINIDE = c(0L, 0L), ACARBOSE = c(0L, 0L),
                     THIAZOLIDINEDIONE = c(0L, 0L), DPP4_INHIBITOR = c(0L, 0L), SGLT2_INHIBITOR = c(1L, 1L), GLP1_RA = c(0L, 0L)), 
                .Names = c("ID", "METFORMIN", "SULPHONYLUREA", "MEGLITINIDE", "ACARBOSE", "THIAZOLIDINEDIONE", "DPP4_INHIBITOR",
                           "SGLT2_INHIBITOR", "GLP1_RA"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

**Data Structure:**

```
 #  ID METFORMIN SULPHONYLUREA MEGLITINIDE ACARBOSE THIAZOLIDINEDIONE DPP4_INHIBITOR SGLT2_INHIBITOR GLP1_RA
 #  1          0             0           0        0                 0              0               1       0
 #  2          0             0           0        0                 0              0               1       0
```

**Desired Data Structure:**

```
 #  ID METFORMIN SULPHONYLUREA MEGLITINIDE ACARBOSE THIAZOLIDINEDIONE DPP4_INHIBITOR SGLT2_INHIBITOR GLP1_RA ORALDM
 #  1          0             0           0        0                 0              0               1       0      1
 #  2          0             0           0        0                 0              0               1       0      1
```

**Code 1:**

```
df %>% mutate(ORALDM = if_else(any(METFORMIN:GLP1_RA) == 1, 1, 0))
```

This does not give the desired output and produces an error:

> Warning messages: 1: In METFORMIN:GLP1_RA :   numerical expression has
>   2 elements: only the first used 2: In METFORMIN:GLP1_RA :   numerical
>   expression has 2 elements: only the first used

**Code 2:**

```
df %>% mutate_if(predicate(any(METFORMIN:GLP1_RA) == 1), 1)
```

This gives an error as well:

> Error in predicate(any(METFORMIN:GLP1_RA) == 1) :    could not find
>   function "predicate"

Comment: What about `df %>% mutate(ORALDM = +(rowSums(.[2:9]) > 0))`?

Comment: @Jaap Thanks! That works! But it does not work when using variable names?

Comment: `df %>% mutate(ORALDM = +(rowSums(select(df, METFORMIN:GLP1_RA)) > 0))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promoting my comments to an answer. With:

```
df %>% mutate(ORALDM = +(rowSums(.[2:9]) > 0))
```

or with (when you want to use variable names):

```
df %>% mutate(ORALDM = +(rowSums(select(df, METFORMIN:GLP1_RA)) > 0))
```

you get:

> ```
>   ID METFORMIN SULPHONYLUREA MEGLITINIDE ACARBOSE THIAZOLIDINEDIONE DPP4_INHIBITOR SGLT2_INHIBITOR GLP1_RA ORALDM
> 1  1         0             0           0        0                 0              0               1       0      1
> 2  2         0             0           0        0                 0              0               1       0      1
> ```

---

The same idea implemented with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- setDT(copy(df))

dt[, ORALDM := +(rowSums(.SD) > 0), .SDcols = METFORMIN:GLP1_RA][]
```

---

NOTE: instead of using `+`, you could also use `as.integer` or `as.numeric`.

Comment: was wondering why `any` would not work. like `df %>% mutate(ORALDM = if_else(any(select(., METFORMIN:GLP1_RA) == 1), 1, 0))` . It gives 1 even if all the values are 0.

Comment: @HNSKD using `any` that way, it also looks column-wise; see also the output of `any(select(df, METFORMIN:GLP1_RA) == 1)`, it gives just one value which is then put into the new column